# File upload to database, file looks like gibberish

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have this code and when I upload a file and look at the gridview it looks like the image below and I'm not sure why. Also the ContentType column is showing up empty as well, I suspect this is linked to the screwed up upload. The comment and GUID works. No error message come up.

```
protected void ButtonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
        string contenttype = String.Empty;

        switch (ext)
        {
            case ".doc":
                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
                break;
            case ".docx":
                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
                break;
            case ".xls":
                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                break;
            case ".xlsx":
                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                break;
            case ".jpg":
                contenttype = "image/jpg";
                break;
            case ".png":
                contenttype = "image/png";
                break;
            case ".gif":
                contenttype = "image/gif";
                break;
            case ".pdf":
                contenttype = "application/pdf";
                break;
        }

        Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

        Guid newGUID = Guid.NewGuid();

        conn.Open();

        string InsertUser = "INSERT INTO UserUpload (ID, Comment,DataUpload, ContentType) VALUES (@ID, @Comment, @DataUpload, @ContentType)";

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(InsertUser, conn);

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", newGUID.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", TextBoxComment.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataUpload", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = bytes;
        com.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = contenttype;

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        LabelMessage.Text = ("Your Upload Is Complete");         

        conn.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        LabelMessage.Text = ("Error:" + ex.Message);

    }
}
```

[image: File Upload Gibberish]

Comment: This is fine actually. you basicly saved the varchar representation of bytes

Comment: What are you expecting it to show?

Comment: I usually do that kind of stuff with the aproach that I convert the file to string compress it and save the compressed thing to the db but try to avoid saving large files to db when ever possable better put it to the filesystem imo

Comment: I see, is there a way to condense this so that it isn't so long in the case of multiple entries. Also any clue as to why ContentType is blank?

Comment: the content type is probably blank cos you are comparing extenstion ".doc" and you probably should be looking for "doc" or something in that matter debug the value

Comment: Why are you showing the binary data in a UI? Are you expecting to see something readable based on the content type?

Comment: No, I just though it would be more condensed. I guess a better idea would be to upload the file to the site, like App_Data folder in VS, instead of directly to the database.

Comment: It's usually better to place the file and then store the path/link to in in the database. A common place to store files, for example, would be in Amazon using S3.

Comment: The content type could be showing as an empty string if the file extension is upper case.  Try changing `switch (ext)` to `switch (ext.ToLower())` and see if that fixes the empty content type.